# How do you prevent a duplicate entry in SQL server of a field that is not a primary

Tags: sql-server

> This is my insert statement that I am currently using. The primary key in this table is **IDNumber**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[AddCustomer]
@IDNumber nvarchar(20),
@Title nchar(10),
@Name nvarchar(50),
@Surname nvarchar(50),
@CellPhone nchar(10),
@AddressLine1 nvarchar(50),
@Suburb nvarchar(40),
@City nvarchar(30),
@PostalCode nchar(10),
@EmailAddress nvarchar(50),
@Password nvarchar(20)
as

insert into Customer(IDNumber,Title,Name,Surname,CellPhone,AddressLine1,Suburb,City,PostalCode,EmailAddress,[Password])
values (@IDNumber,@Title,@Name,@Surname,@CellPhone,@AddressLine1,@Suburb,@City,@PostalCode,@EmailAddress,@Password)
```

> Now I would like the sql statement that will prevent a duplicate email address from being inserted.

Comment: [Creating Unique Indexes] (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms175132(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at unique constraints http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190024.aspx

```
ALTER TABLE Customer
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_email UNIQUE (EmailAddress); 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

That should actually be a constraint on the table column.

```
ALTER TABLE Customer
ADD CONSTRAINT EmailAddress_Uniqueness_Constraint UNIQUE (EmailAddress)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create unique index/key on Email column.
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Email ON TABLE(EMAIL);